# The test couldn't be found in the assembly

Tags: c#, nunit, pnunit

I was trying to execute a sample PNunit tests, but it is failing with the following error

```
The test xxx couldn't be found in the assembly xxx.dll
```

I have followed the Pnunit doc, but it is not helpful.

[image: Project Refs]

Here is the test case

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TestLibraries
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class PuniTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void EqualTo19()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(19, (15 + 4));
        }
    }
}
```

and the test.conf file

```
<TestGroup>
  <Variables>
    <Variable name="$agent_host" value="localhost" />
  </Variables>

  <ParallelTests>
      <ParallelTest>
        <Name>Testing</Name>
        <Tests>
          <TestConf>
            <Name>Testing</Name>
            <Assembly>pnunit35.dll</Assembly>
            <TestToRun>TestLibraries.PuniTest.EqualTo19</TestToRun>
            <Machine>$agent_host:8080</Machine>
          </TestConf>
        </Tests>
      </ParallelTest>
    </ParallelTests>

</TestGroup>
```

I have compiled the code, copied the "pnunit35.dll" and "test.conf" files to "**NUnit.Runners.Net4.2.6.4\tools**" folder to run the tests

And run the following commands (in batch file) to start the agent and run the scripts from Nunit test runner folder

```
start pnunit-agent 8080 .
pnunit-launcher test.conf
```

On running the batch scripts, tests are failing with the following error

```
The test TestLibraries.PuniTest.EqualTo19 couldn't be found in the assembly pnunit35.dll
```

Could some body please look into this?, thanks in advance

Comment: The name is `EqualTo19`, not `EqualTo20 `

Comment: thanks for quick response. Sorry, that was a typo. An error message appeared for other test. The Actual message is " The test TestLibraries.PuniTest.EqualTo19 couldn't be found in the assembly pnunit35.dll"

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance you're missing the [NUnit Test Adapter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnitTestAdapter) in Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi @dawid-dworak, just tried by adding the Nunit test adapter, I still see the same issue

Comment: The NUnit Test Adapter really has no connection with this scenario at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a processor architecture mismatch. If your project is 64bit, go to test -> test settings -> default processor architecure -> x64.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone,

Finally I found root cause of the problem, it is the pNunit versions which is incompatible with the NUnit-3.6.0 and Nunit.Runner-4.2.6.4 I was using in my project.

When I googled about the issue, I found that pNunit-2.6.4 is not compatible with the latest Nunit-3.6.0. So, I have changed Nunit and NUnit.Runners to 2.6.4. Then the tests worked without any issues.

**Update:**
Use .Net Framework 3.5

**Update2:**  [***.Net Framework 4.5***]
if you are working on .Net Framework 4 and above, start PNunit-agent in compatiblity mode.

Edit "pnunit-agent.exe.config" file in text editor and add the following code in 'configuration'

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
</startup>
```

Close the pnunit-agent and re-run that will solve the issue